# Convert string to date SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query when I need to convert a string to datetime, I use

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, '')
```

but it's still not working. My column `fechac` is of type `Datetime`.

If I pass in for example `'2019-11-20 00:03:56.120'`, the query works but I don't need the time because is a parameter from an application web and I send the date example '2019-11-20'. Thanks!

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE cb.fechac = CONVERT(DATETIME, '2019-11-20');
```

Comment: Use the format `yyyyMMdd`. With the `datetime` datatype `yyyy-MM-dd` is ambiguous.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table cb
WHERE cast(cb.fechac as date) = convert(date, '2019-11-20', 23)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution

Comment: This isn't the best idea at all... This can have signicant performances impacts, @Rodrigo . Use proper date logic with `>=` and `<`. [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34047/140734)

Comment: @Larnu, `where cb.fechac between convert(datetime, '2019-11-20T00:00:00.000', 126) and convert(datetime, '2019-11-20T23:59:59.999', 126)` will also work.  It looks like this will involve half as many reads (so twice as fast).  I suppose it will come down to how often the code needs to be run and how clean the code should look for the next person who must support it.

Comment: Generally, using `BETWEEN` is just a bad idea when using dates that have a time component, @dougp . The `>=` AND `<` logic is much more concise. Especially as you can easily write things like `DateColumn >= @Date and DateColumn < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date)`, rather than `DateColumn BETWEEN @Date AND DATEADD(MILLISECOND, -3, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @Date))` (assuming `DateColumn` and `@date` is a `datetime`)

Answer (score 2):

Use the format `yyyyMMdd`. With the `datetime` datatype `yyyy-MM-dd` is ambiguous. Otherwise, use a [style code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles):

```
CONVERT(datetime,'2019-11-20',126);
CONVERT(datetime,'20191120')
```

*Reading a lot through the lines in the comments here, however, are you **actually** after..?:*

```
WHERE fechac >= '20191120'
  AND fechac < '20191121'
```

Final reading through the lines. it appears the OP is actuaklly passing a parameter (I **assume** of the data type `date`), therefore...

```
WHERE fechac >= @fechac
  AND fechac < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @fechac)
```

Comment: Thank you, the query sintaxis is fine but give me 0 rows when I execute the query

Comment: Then that would mean there are no rows where the time is **exactly** `2019-11-20T00:00:00.000` @Rodrigo .

Comment: You're right there isn't, in that case how could I do it? I need the field fechac to be datetime but in this query I don't need the time because I use the time for auditory

Comment: *"Because I need the time but i don't need for this query"* That doesn't make sense. You either do, or you don't.

Comment: The part OP is actually after is buried inside the question!

Comment: I better get my shovel then, @SalmanA , so I can start digging. :)

Comment: I edit the answer @Larnu. In this case is better change the type of the field right

Comment: By the "field" do you mean the column, @Rodrigo ? If so, no you should not be using `CONVERT` on a column in the `WHERE`; that can have significant performance implications.

Comment: Yes the column, but the query should me return rows. I my table I have many data and  in the column fechac for example : 2019-11-21 18:40:33.787, but in my application I only send the parameter in this format, for example: '2019-11-21'

Comment: Then you want the second query I posted, @Rodrigo, with the `>=` and `<` logic.

Comment: Wait, *"I only send the parameter in this format"* your parameter should have **no** format; it should be sending a `datetime` parameter, not a string. If you're sending a string, like that, that infers your injecting your values not parametrising it.

Comment: I only send one fechac, like the first query you posted. I will change the type of the column maybe. Thanks

Comment: *"I will change the type of the column maybe."* which will mean you lose all your time data, @Rodrigo . You explicitly said you need that. Chnaging the data type will mean it is **permenantly** lost. I've added a final guess, but if that isn't the solution you need to reword your question, as you're making little sense here. The query **isn't** parametrised, and the time does matter; which you've said you're doing to opposite of.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on any system, regardless of internationalization settings:

```
WHERE cb.fechac=convert(DATE,'20191120');
```